# Numba issues multiprocessing UserWarning when running in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, numba, suppress-warnings

When running a script with numba on AWS Lambda, I always get this warning:

```
/var/task/numba/npyufunc/parallel.py:300: UserWarning: Could not obtain multiprocessing lock due to OS level error: Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Since AWS Lambda does not support multiprocessing, is there any way to ignore this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to the python file where your lambda handle is imported:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', message='Could not obtain multiprocessing lock')
```

This will ignore that specific warning, while still printing any other warnings your script may produce.